# using port 80 in Websocket server

Tags: websocket, portforwarding, php-socket

I am developing a chat server in php using html 5 and Websocket

I want to connect the websocket to a subdomain with port 80 using something like the following code:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://subdomain.mydomain.com:80");
```

How can my Apache sever listen to port 80.Is it even possible or not.

If it's not possible , is there a way by which i can forward data from port 80 to another port(ex:8080)

The reason why i am doing so is that i wanna use the websocket beside proxy.

Is there any other solution handling this issue .